# Recompiling Go Echo project when source changes with compileDaemon

Tags: go

I'm trying to make compileDaemon to compile and serve my Go Echo application whenever I make changes to the source code. The commands that I tried are,

```
CompileDaemon -build="go run main.go"
```

and

```
CompileDaemon -command="go run main.go"
```

both of them starts `CompileDaemon` with the following output

```
2018/12/17 10:40:29 Running build command!
2018/12/17 10:40:29 Build ok.
```

Whenever I update the source, the output repeats but my server is not starting . How do I make compileDaemon to run my echo server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add the project directory to the command, for the current directory `.`,

```
CompileDaemon -directory=. -command="go run main.go"
```

which will work.